# Different result even though both stored procs are using the same logic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

To begin with, I have a longer version of a stored proc like below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetLastPoolBalance
@IsApproved BIT,
@PoolId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@PoolId IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 4 pb.PoolBalanceID,
        pb.PoolID,
        pb.EndDate,
        pb.TransactionCategoryID,
        pb.Balance,
        pb.IsApproved,
        pb.Creator,
        pb.CreationDate,
        pb.Approver,
        pb.ApprovalDate
        FROM dbo.PoolBalance pb
        WHERE pb.IsApproved = @IsApproved
        ORDER BY pb.EndDate DESC 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 4 pb.PoolBalanceID,
        pb.PoolID,
        pb.EndDate,
        pb.TransactionCategoryID,
        pb.Balance,
        pb.IsApproved,
        pb.Creator,
        pb.CreationDate,
        pb.Approver,
        pb.ApprovalDate
        FROM dbo.PoolBalance pb
        WHERE pb.IsApproved = @IsApproved AND pb.PoolID = @PoolId 
        ORDER BY pb.EndDate DESC 
    END
END
GO
```

And its result is:

```css
table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PoolBalanceId</th>
                <th>PoolId</th>
                <th>EndDate</th>
                <th>TransactionalCategoryId</th>
                <th>Balance</th>
                <th>IsApproved</th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>CreationDate</th>
                <th>Approver</th>
                <th>ApprovalDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Add table rows with data here -->
            <tr>
                <td>36631</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-11-30 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>15272089.18</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.597</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.597</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36630</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-11-30 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>6444610902.64</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.567</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.567</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36627</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-10-31 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>10666151.02</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.450</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36626</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-10-31 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>6285368646.30</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.417</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.417</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Looking at the stored proc, I would immediate know that I can do a shorter and more efficient. So, I use a single `SELECT` statement with a modify `WHERE` clause instead of using `IF` and `ELSE` branches. Here is the updated stored proc:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetLastPoolBalance1
@IsApproved BIT,
@PoolId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 4 pb.PoolBalanceID,
    pb.PoolID,
    pb.EndDate,
    pb.TransactionCategoryID,
    pb.Balance,
    pb.IsApproved,
    pb.Creator,
    pb.CreationDate,
    pb.Approver,
    pb.ApprovalDate
    FROM dbo.PoolBalance pb
    WHERE pb.IsApproved = @IsApproved AND
    (
        @PoolId IS NULL OR
        pb.PoolID = @PoolId
    )
    ORDER BY pb.EndDate DESC

END
GO
```

I'm pretty sure that the login in my modified works exactly the same with the original stored proc. However, when I run mine, it returns a different result. Here is my table result:

```css
table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PoolBalanceId</th>
                <th>PoolId</th>
                <th>EndDate</th>
                <th>TransactionalCategoryId</th>
                <th>Balance</th>
                <th>IsApproved</th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>CreationDate</th>
                <th>Approver</th>
                <th>ApprovalDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Add table rows with data here -->
            <tr>
                <td>36630</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-11-30 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>6444610902.64</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.567</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.567</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36631</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-11-30 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>15272089.18</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.597</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-12-06 11:27:57.597</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36626</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-10-31 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>6285368646.30</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.417</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.417</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36627</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>2022-10-31 00:00:00.000</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>10666151.02</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.450</td>
                <td>504</td>
                <td>2022-11-04 14:24:46.450</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In my modified stored proc, the results for `PoolBalanceId` is opposite from the original stored proc. I look at both stored procs and cannot figure out what's going wrong with my modified stored proc.

Would be nice if someone can tell me the difference between them ? and if possible, how would I write a shorter and more efficient one than the original version ? Thank you

Comment: Actually you second version might lead to worse performance because SQL Server generally doesn't do ORs well. I usually use dynamic SQL to handle this kinda of multiple parameter selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bite.....I think it's due to the Order By clause....my thinking is, multiple records may have the same EndDate and the order of the records with the same date isn't explicitly defined so the database MAY return them in different orders.  This could result in the difference in PoolBalanceID between the two different SPs because the db engine may determine there are different execution plans between the 2 sps, impacting the order of records with the same EndDate.

I'd try adding an additional column in the order by clause like:

```
    ORDER By pb.EndDate Desc, pb.PoolBalanceID
```

please let me know if that works or add some data to reproduce it, I'm curious!

Comment: Yeah. It works that way. I need to modify it a bit `ORDER By pb.EndDate Desc, pb.PoolBalanceID Desc` Thank you @pauliec